# Trouble printing out values from an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I'm writing this program to calculate the area and perimeter of a polygon when given a certain set of input values. So far everything has worked successfully and I'm happy with the output up to stage 3, the problem I am encountering seems quite trivial but I can't seem to locate it. In stage 3 where I am attempting to calculate the largest polygon area I need to print out the (x,y) coordinates assigned to that polygon. I have a method of determining the largest polygon, which works and outputs the correct polygon, but when I try and read the (x,y) coordinates from that polygon into another array and print those values I get nothing in return, even though it all compiles fine. I'm mainly concerned about printing out the values in the array over all else.

This is the output I require:

```
Stage 3
=======
Largest polygon is 15643
   x_val   y_val
    1.0     2.0
    4.0     5.0
    7.8     3.5
    5.0     0.4
    1.0     0.4
```

This is the output I am receiving:

```
Stage 3
=======
Largest polygon is 15643
   x_val   y_val
```

Here is my written code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_POLYS 100
#define MAX_PTS 100
#define END_INPUT 0
#define PI 3.141592653589793
#define PER_ROW 5

double eccentricity(double perimeter, double area) {
    double eccen;
    eccen = (perimeter*perimeter)/(area*4*PI);
    return eccen;
}

double getDistance(int npoints, double x[], double y[]) {
    double distance = 0.0, dx, dy;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < npoints; ++i) {
        dx = x[(i+1) % npoints] - x[i];                  
        dy = y[(i+1) % npoints] - y[i];
        distance += sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);             
    }
    return distance;
}

double poly_area(int length, double x[], double y[]) {
    double area = 0.0;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
         j = (i + 1) % length;   
        area += (x[i] * y[j] - x[j] * y[i]);
    }
    area = area / 2;
    area = (area > 0 ? area : -1 * area);

    return (area);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int npoints, point, poly_id, c, k;
    int npoints_largest, poly_id_largest;
    double x[MAX_PTS], y[MAX_PTS];
    double Ax[MAX_POLYS], Ay[MAX_POLYS];
    double perimeter, area = 0, eccen, largest_area;

/* ================================Stage 1=================================== */

    if(scanf("%d %d", &npoints, &poly_id)) {
        for (point = 0; point < npoints; ++point) {
            scanf("%lf %lf", &(x[point]), &(y[point]));         
        }
    }
    perimeter = getDistance(npoints, x, y);              

    area = poly_area(npoints, x, y); 

    eccen = eccentricity(perimeter, area);

    printf("\nStage 1\n=======\n");
    printf("First polygon is %d\n", poly_id);
    printf("   x_val   y_val\n");
    for (point = 0; point < npoints; ++point) {
    printf("    %2.1f     %2.1f\n", x[point], y[point]);
    }   
    printf("perimeter    = %3.2f m\n", perimeter);
    printf("area         =  %3.2f m^2\n", area);
    printf("eccentricity =  %3.2f\n", eccen);

/* ================================Stage 2=================================== */

    printf("\nStage 2\n=======\n");
    for (c=0; c<PER_ROW; c++) {
        printf("+-------");
        if(c == PER_ROW-1) {
            printf("+");
        }
    }
    printf("\n|    id |  nval | perim |  area | eccen |\n");
    for (c=0; c<PER_ROW; c++) {
        printf("+-------");
        if(c == PER_ROW-1) {
            printf("+\n");
        }
    }
    printf("| %5d | %5d | %5.2f | %5.2f | %5.2f |\n", poly_id, npoints,
        perimeter, area, eccen);
    while (scanf("%d %d", &npoints, &poly_id) == 2) {
        for(k = 0; k < npoints; k++) {
            scanf("%lf %lf", &(x[k]), &(y[k]));
            perimeter = getDistance(npoints, x, y);
            area = poly_area(npoints, x, y);
            eccen = eccentricity(perimeter, area);
        }   
        if (area > largest_area) {
            largest_area = area;
            poly_id_largest = poly_id;
            npoints_largest = npoints;

            Ax[k] = x[k];  // here is where I attempt to read the largest area
            Ay[k] = y[k];  // into another array.
        }   

    printf("| %5d | %5d | %5.2f | %5.2f | %5.2f |\n", poly_id, npoints,
        perimeter, area, eccen);
    }

    for (c=0; c<PER_ROW; c++) {
        printf("+-------");
        if(c == PER_ROW-1) {
            printf("+\n");
        }
    }

/* ==============================Stage 3===================================== */    

    printf("\nStage 3\n=======\n");
    printf("Largest polygon is %d\n", poly_id_largest);
    printf("   x_val   y_val\n");
    for (k = 0; k < npoints; ++k) {                     // trying to loop and
        printf("    %2.1f     %2.1f\n", Ax[k], Ay[k]);  // print the values
    }                         // prints out nothing though?
    return 0;
}
```

If anyone could point out a mistake in my code or a tip on what to do it'd be appreciated!

Comment: You may want to look at [**Issue with program output**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815204/issue-with-program-output). It looks surprisingly similar to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the npoints_largest variable in your final for loop:

```
for (k = 0; k < npoints_largest; ++k) {
```

Comment: I tried this and it prints an output but all the point are 0.0

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting.

So you are inputting 5 polygon inputs from the user? 
So the why is poly_id_largest so high?

Please set your "Largest_area" to 0 first.

The answers are not right, its never going into this block of code.

```
   if (area > largest_area) {
        largest_area = area;
        poly_id_largest = poly_id;
        npoints_largest = npoints;

        Ax[k] = x[k];  // here is where I attempt to read the largest area
        Ay[k] = y[k];  // into another array.
    }
```

Comment: There can be anywhere from 1  to 100 polygons on input and the poly_id is the ID for each polygon to know which one it is. poly_id_largest just means this is the id of the largest polygon. So that block of code is what I'm using to find the largest polygon. It has successfully identified which polygon but has not put the (x,y) coordinates from that polygon into the new array. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, at this line `double perimeter, area = 0, eccen, largest_area;`change it to `double perimeter, area = 0, eccen, largest_area=0;`

Comment: Also change the second part 

  `if (area > largest_area) {
        largest_area = area;
        poly_id_largest = poly_id;
        npoints_largest = npoints;

        Ax[0] = x[k];  // here is where I attempt to read the largest area
        Ay[0] = y[k];  // into another array.
    } `

as so 

You can have only one polygon with the largest area right?

Comment: and here too
`for (k = 0; k < 1; ++k) {                     
        printf("    %2.1f     %2.1f\n", Ax[k], Ay[k]); 
    }`

Comment: All I get is 0.0 values for all the x, y coordinates